# Is every ring homomorphism $\phi: A \to B$ $k$-algebra homomorphism, where A,B are finitely generated $k$-algebra?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A,B$ be finitely generated $k$-algebra and $\phi: A \to B$ be a ring homomorphism which maps $1$ to $1$. Is $\phi$ necessarily $k$-algebra homomorphism? If not please give an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let $k=A=B=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ and $\phi(a+b\sqrt{2}) = a-b\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Please respect [the guidelines for enforcing quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Thank you.